# add sound with time interval in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created a vb.net app
In the form 2 text box and one button
Textbox1 displays current system time and textbox2, 1 hour later.
So when i press the button , sound should play exactly after 1 hour of time i pressed button. 
So if I press button for 5 different time in half an hour, the sound should play after 1 hour starting from that button press.

I have following code to play sound and to display two different time in text box.

```
Private Sub ESREntry_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim mytime As System.DateTime
            Dim hours As Double = 1
            mytime = Now.ToShortTimeString


            StartTimetxt.Text = mytime
            EndTimeTxt.Text = mytime.AddHours(+hours)

            Timer1.Start()
End sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            Dim hours As Double = 1
            Me.StartTimetxt.Text = TimeOfDay
            Me.EndTimeTxt.Text = TimeOfDay.AddHours(+hours).ToShortTimeString
 End Sub
```

Comment: When dragging a timer to your form, it's `Enabled` property is False by default.  Have you either enabled it in the designer, or somewhere else in your code set `Timer1.Enabled = True`?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the problem you are facing. The code you have given above will update both the textboxes. But your question is about sound. Can you update your question with the code you have written so far for sound.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Console.Beep()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Console.Beep()

End Sub
```